# Google Map API V3 - Two markers displayed on LG7 Android 4.0

Tags: android, google-maps, hybrid-mobile-app

Markers are double and the markers are dragged together.
The bug appear only when draggable property is set to TRUE.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : new google.maps.LatLng({{lat}}, {{lg}}),
            map : map,
            draggable: true
        });
```

Any idea ?
Gmap Bug ,Device bug, technology bug ... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have something similiar. I have this bug or failure when I change the location of the overlay. So if I have one marker and I change the position of it then I have one marker on the old pos. and one marker at the new position. When i force the map to reload by zooming in or out the "old" marker disappears.

But I can't really help you. So may be you try to force gmap to reload by changing overlay coordinates and so on.

I have this only with my Samsung galaxy S3 Android 4.0. 2 other Galaxy S1 with different Android 2.X versions work fine. Desktopbrowser works fine.

Look here for : [Google Maps API v3 in PhoneGap: markers not drawing properly after move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505692/google-maps-api-v3-in-phonegap-markers-not-drawing-properly-after-move)

I think this will help you. But it can't help me because I am using overlays and there is no property optimized.